# cashU Soap integration

Tags: php, soap

I called SoapClient and the response should be the `$Transaction_Code` but nothing returns from cashu>>> any help?

```
<?php

            ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
            ini_set('customer_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0');
    //The above line will add the User-Agent to the header of your request, and the soap library 'SoapClient' will add the Host header nameautomatically.
            $merchant_id = 'system';
            $encryption_key = 'recharge';
            $amount = 100; // This value will be posted from the above HTML page
            $currency = 'SAR';
            $display_text = 'Hello 111222212121';
            $language = 'en';

            $session_id = 'boody'.rand(0000,9999);
            $txt1 = "item";
            $testmode = 0;
    // The below Parameters are not required, especially in the default Merchant Checkout Page:
            $txt2 = '';
            $txt3 = '';
            $txt4 = '';
            $txt5 = '';
            $service_name = 'Default';
    // If using Enhanced Encryption:
            $token = md5(strtolower($merchant_id) . ':' . $amount . ':' .
                strtolower($currency) . ':' . strtolower($session_id) . ':' . $encryption_key);

            if($testmode == 0){
                $domain_url = "https://sandbox.cashu.com/secure/payment.wsdl";
            }else{
                $domain_url = "https://secure.cashu.com/payment.wsdl";
            }
            $client = new SoapClient($domain_url, array('trace' => true));
            // Change the URL to "https://secure.cashu.com/payment.wsdl" for Live Area.
          //  $request = $client-> DoPaymentRequest($merchant_id, $token, $display_text, $currency, $amount, $language, $session_id, $txt1, $txt2, $txt3, $txt4, $txt5, $testmode, $service_name);
            $request = $client-> __soapCall('DoPaymentRequest',$merchant_id, $token, $display_text, $currency, $amount, $language, $session_id, $txt1, $txt2, $txt3, $txt4, $txt5, $testmode, $service_name);

    //The Parameters must be in this order: merchant_id, token,display_text, currency, amount, language, session_id, txt1, txt2, txt3,txt4, txt5, test_mode, service_name

            //Get transaction code from the response
            $tmp = strstr($request, '=');
            $Transaction_Code = substr($tmp, 1);

            echo $Transaction_Code;

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the second parameter for __soapCall accepts the arguments in an array. So you'll have to send all your reqeust parameters in an array form. 
http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php